# django NOT NULL constraint failed:

Tags: javascript, django

I am getting 2 errors trying to add products to my cart in a website in django.

IntegrityError at /apiadd/
NOT NULL constraint failed: cianshop_basketitem.basket_id_id

in my console i see this:
"
productindividual?id=1:136          POST http://127.0.0.1:8000/apiadd/ 500 (Internal Server Error)
addToCart.onclick @ productindividual?id=1:136
VM55:1 Uncaught (in promise) SyntaxError: Unexpected token I in JSON at position 0
"

this is my models.py file:

```
from dataclasses import is_dataclass
from django.db import models
from django.contrib.auth.models import AbstractUser

class APIUser(AbstractUser):
    pass

class Product(models.Model):
    id = models.IntegerField(primary_key=True)
    name = models.TextField()
    description = models.TextField(null=True)
    price = models.DecimalField(max_digits=6, decimal_places=2, default=0.0) #9999.99
    image = models.FileField(upload_to='products', null=True)

class Basket(models.Model):
    id = models.IntegerField(primary_key=True)
    user_id = models.ForeignKey(APIUser, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    is_active = models.BooleanField(default=True)

class BasketItem(models.Model):
    id = models.IntegerField(primary_key=True)
    basket_id = models.ForeignKey(Basket, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    product_id = models.ForeignKey(Product, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    quantity = models.IntegerField(default=1)

    def price(self):
        return self.product_id.price * self.quantity
    
    def product_name(self):
        return self.product_id.name

class Order(models.Model):
    id = models.IntegerField(primary_key=True)
    basket_id = models.ForeignKey(Basket, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    user_id = models.ForeignKey(APIUser, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    datetime_ordered = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    total_price = models.DecimalField(max_digits=6, decimal_places=2, default=0.0)
    shipping_addr = models.TextField(default="")
```

this is my basket.ejs file:

```
  <script>
    window.onload = ()=>{
      let params = window.location.search;
      let urlParams = new URLSearchParams(params);
      let productID = urlParams.get("id");
      // http://127.0.0.1:8000/api/products/id 
      if(productID != null && typeof(productID)!= 'undefined'){
          fetch('http://127.0.0.1:8000/api/products/'+productID)
          .then(resp => resp.json())
          .then(data => {
              // console.log(data);
              if('detail' in data){
                  // display some generic product not found error
                  alert("Product Not Found!");
              }
              else{
                  let name = data['name'];
                  let desc = data['description'];
                  let price = data['price'];
                  // let image= data['image'];
                  // display the product data 
                  let nameElem = document.getElementById("myname"); // returns the specific DOM node , the P tag with id="myparagraphid"
                  nameElem.innerHTML=name;
                  let descElem = document.getElementById("mydesc"); // returns the specific DOM node , the P tag with id="myparagraphid"
                  descElem.innerHTML=desc;
                  let priceElem = document.getElementById("myprice"); // returns the specific DOM node , the P tag with id="myparagraphid"
                  priceElem.innerHTML=price;
                  document.getElementById("myimg").src = data["image"];
              }
            });
      }

      let addToCart = document.createElement("button"); // create a button
      document.getElementById("mybutton").appendChild(addToCart)
      addToCart.innerHTML = "Add to cart"; // set the text of the button 
      addToCart.onclick = ()=>{
        // code for when the button is clicked
        fetch('http://127.0.0.1:8000/apiadd/', {
          method: 'POST',
          headers: {
            'Content-Type': 'application/json',
            'Accept': 'application/json',
            'Authorization': 'Bearer '+localStorage.getItem("access")
          },
          body: JSON.stringify({
            "product_id": parseInt(productID)
          })
        })
        .then(response=>response.json())
        .then(data=>{
            // display an add to cart success message
            // console.log(response)
          });
      }
    }

  </script>
```

Comment: There is no issue in your models. The issue is probably with the way you are sending data from frontend to backend or the way you are reading the data sent from frontend to backend. You are trying to create BasketItem with data received from the frontend. But it seems like the value of  basket_id is not what you are expecting it to be. Perhaps update your question with more details on how you have sent data and received them.

Comment: I have updated to show my basket.ejs file

Comment: Please add your django view as well which handles the request